# How to replace date part in filename with current date

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

How to replace only date part to current date of all files present in diretory in unix.

**Folder path:** `C:/shan`

**Sample files:**

```
CN_Apria_837p_20180924.txt  
DN_Apria_837p_20150502.txt  
GN_Apria_837p_20160502.txt  
CH_Apria_837p_20170502.txt  
CU_Apria_837p_20180502.txt  
PN_Apria_837p_20140502.txt  
CN_Apria_837p_20101502.txt
```

**Desired result should be:**

```
CN_Apria_837p_20190502.txt  
DN_Apria_837p_20190502.txt  
GN_Apria_837p_20190502.txt  
CH_Apria_837p_20190502.txt  
CU_Apria_837p_20190502.txt  
PN_Apria_837p_20190502.txt  
CN_Apria_837p_20190502.txt
```

---

**Edit:**

I'm completely new to unix sell scripting. I tried this below, however it's not working.

```sh
#!/bin/bash

for i in ls $1 | grep -E '[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}'
do
  x=echo $i | grep -oE '[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}'
  y=echo $i | sed "s/$x/$(date +%F)/g"
  mv $1/$i $1/$y 2>/dev/null #incase if old date is same as current date
done
```

Comment: You can use sed, checkout online for tutorials: https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/09/unix-sed-tutorial-replace-text-inside-a-file-using-substitute-command/?utm_source=sitekickr&utm_medium=snip_button

Comment: Since I am new bee to unix I couldn't able to understand the information in link provided . If possible could you please help me with script

Comment: @shan455 : Would you mind accepting one of the answers, if they solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

The below should do this

```
for f in $(find /path/to/files -name "*_*_*_*.txt")
do 
  newname=$(echo "$f" | sed -r "s/[12][0-9]{3}[01][0-9][0-3][0-9]/$(date '+%Y%m%d')/g")   
  mv "$f" "$newname" 
done
```

Comment: @shan455 forgot to enclose file name pattern in double quotes. Please see updated answer

Comment: Gettng an other error  : sed: illegal option -- r, 
my server is AIX

Comment: Error: mv: ./shan/CN_Apria_837p_20180924.txt and ./shan/CN_Apria_837p_20180924.txt are identical.

Answer (score 1):

I would use regular expressions here. From the bash man-page:

> An  additional  binary  operator,  =~,  is available, with the same
>     precedence as == and !=.  When it is used, the string to the  right
>     of  the  operator  is considered an extended regular expression and
>     matched accordingly (as in regex(3)).  The return value is 0 if the
>     string  matches  the  pattern,  and  1  otherwise. .... Substrings
>     matched by  parenthesized  subexpressions within the regular
>     expression are saved  in  the  array  variable  BASH_REMATCH. ...
>     The element of BASH_REMATCH with indexn  is the portion of the
>     string matching the nth parenthesized sub-expression.

Hence, assuming that the variable `x` holds the name of one of the files
in question, the code

```
if [[ $x =~ ^(.*_)[0-9]+([.]txt$) ]]
then
  mv "$x" "$BASH_REMATCH[1]$(date +%Y%m%d)$BASH_REMATCH[2]"
fi
```

first tests roughly whether the file indeed follows the required naming scheme, and then modifies the name accordingly.

Of course in practice, you will tailor the regexp to match your application better. Only you can know what variations in the file name are permitted.

Answer (score 0):

Try this [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/)-clean code:

```
#! /bin/bash -p

readonly dir=$1

shopt -s nullglob  # Make glob patterns that match nothing expand to nothing

readonly dateglob='20[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
currdate=$(date '+%Y%m%d')

# shellcheck disable=SC2231
for path in "$dir"/*_${dateglob}.* ; do
    name=${path##*/}
    newname=${name/_${dateglob}./_${currdate}.}
    if [[ $newname != "$name" ]] ; then
        newpath="$dir/$newname"
        printf "%q -> %q\\n" "$path" "$newpath"
        mv -i -- "$path" "$newpath"
    fi
done
```

- `shopt -s nullglob` stops the code trying to process a garbage path if nothing matches the glob pattern in `for path in ...`.
- The pattern assigned to `dateglob` assumes that you will not have to process dates before 2000 (or after 2099!).  Change it if that assumption is not valid.
- The `# shellcheck ...` line is to prevent [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) warning about the use of `${dateglob}` without quotes.  The quotes would be wrong in this case because they would prevent the glob pattern being expanded.
- The pattern used to match filenames (`*_${dateglob}.*`) will match many more forms of filename than the examples given (e.g. `A_20180313.tar.gz`).  You might want to change it.
- See [Removing part of a string (BashFAQ/100 (How do I do string manipulation in bash?))](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/100#Removing_part_of_a_string) for information about the Bash string manipulation mechanisms used (`${path##...}`, `${name/...}`).
- I've added a `printf` to output details of what is being moved.
- The `-i` option to `mv` prompts for confirmation if a file would be overwritten.  This turns out to be an issue for the example files because both `CN_Apria_837p_20180924.txt` and `CN_Apria_837p_20101502.txt` are identical except for the date, so the code tries to rename them to the same thing.
- If any of the files with dates in their names have names beginning with '.', the code will not process them.  Add line `shopt -s dotglob` somewhere before the loop if that is an issue.